# how to cancel a paticular UILocalNotification in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uilocalnotification

I have a cell in a table view which has a button for scheduling notifications. Is it possible to delete or cancel a notification for that particular cell without affecting the notifications scheduled by other cells ? I want to delete or cancel the particular notification using the same button.
If so, please help me with a sample swift code.

```
@IBAction func setNotification(sender: UIButton!) {

        cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)) as! CustomTableViewCell
        if sender.selected {

            sender.selected = false
             }else {
currentRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude ,longitude:longitude), radius: radius, identifier: identifier)
regionMonitor()
            manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            sender.selected = true } }
```

code for `didEnterRegion()`

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion!) {
            localNotification.regionTriggersOnce = true
            localNotification.alertBody = "you have reached"
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
            NSLog("Entering region") }
```

Comment: Could you add the code you use for scheduling the notifications?

Comment: @ZeMoon i've updated my question

Comment: Let me get this right... You are scheduling immediate notifications, right?

Comment: @ZeMoon I am scheduling location based notification. When the user enters the region the notification gets triggered. I want, if for some reason the user changes his mind about the notification and clicks the button again to cancel it, the notification should not trigger if he enters the region.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please upvote and accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could save a unique identifier for each `UILocalNotification` in the `userInfo` and then loop through them all to find the unique id and delete it:

```
var app:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
    if let localNotifications = app.scheduledLocalNotifications {
        for oneEvent in localNotifications {
            var notification = oneEvent as UILocalNotification
            if let userInfoCurrent = notification.userInfo as? [String:AnyObject],
                let uid = userInfoCurrent["uid"] as? String {
                if uid == uidtodelete {
                    //Cancelling local notification
                    app.cancelLocalNotification(notification)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Updated to **Swift 3** and improved to prevent `nil` crashes

Comment: sorry for the late reply.  How can i save a unique identifier for each `UILocalNotification` in the `userInfo` ?

Comment: i was thinking of something like
 `let userInfo: NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: what goes here ? , forKey: what goes here ?)
 localNotification.userInfo = userInfo as [NSObject : AnyObject]` **What goes inside object and key ?**

Comment: this is my code for canceling the notification
`for notification in UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications! {                 if (notification.userInfo!["What goes here ?"] as! String! == What goes here ?) {
                
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification) 
                    break
                }
            }`

Comment: let userInfo: NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object:"your-unique-id-12345", forKey:"uid")

Comment: If my answer helped you, please upvote and accept it. Thanks

Comment: this gives an error sometimes `unexp found nil ..`, do you have any idea ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to make sure it doesn't crash. I don't know which variable was nil and why.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/) to save the setting.

To enable or disable the setting in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "ShouldShowRegionEnteredNotification") //true or false
```

Then you can check the setting like so:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion!) {

    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("ShouldShowRegionEnteredNotification"))
    {
        localNotification.regionTriggersOnce = true
        localNotification.alertBody = "you have reached"
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
        NSLog("Entering region")
    }
}
```